# how to get <Field> values in redux-form 7.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

```html
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const { Add, noteList } = this.props;
    Add('this is title's value' , 'this is content's value');
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, noteList: { list } } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleClick)}>
        <div>
          <Field className="title" name="title" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Field className="content" name="content" component="textarea" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => { list ? this.handleClick : e.preventDefault(); }}>add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

when i click the button, i hope to get these two values into a function Add as two arguments to do something async, what should i do , help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field values in `handleClick` function can can be obtained `onSubmit` as an object.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(values) {
    const { Add, noteList } = this.props;
    Add(values.title , values.content);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, noteList: { list } } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleClick)}>
        <div>
          <Field className="title" name="title" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Field className="content" name="content" component="textarea" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => { list ? this.handleClick : e.preventDefault(); }}>add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!!  . I can continue to do my form demo

Comment: Glad to have helped :)